# TypeError of Meteor.subscribe function on using Meteor' server render in react router v4

Tags: meteor, server, react-router

I am using the Meteor's server render package with React router v4 but I am getting a TypeError, that Meteor.subscribe is not a function, I am unable to figure out as to why this happening or what is exactly wrong

Here is my code on the client:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {RenderRoutes} from '../imports/api/routes.jsx'
import { onPageLoad } from 'meteor/server-render';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
  Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch
 } from 'react-router-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

const Application = () => (
   <Router history={history}>
      <RenderRoutes/>
   </Router>
);

onPageLoad(()=> {
   ReactDOM.render(<Application/>, document.getElementById('react-root'));
});
```

And on the server:

```
onPageLoad((sink) => {
   const context = {};

   const App = props => (
      <StaticRouter location={props.location} context={context}>
       <RenderRoutes/>
      </StaticRouter>
   );

  sink.renderIntoElementById('app', renderToString(<App location=
   {sink.request.url} />));
  });
```

I was able to get a very simple app properly working using the above, it's the subscriptions and createcontainer which are bringing in the error, is there a separate way to deal with them?

Here is how I'm subscribing on the client:

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  const handle1 = Meteor.subscribe('categories');
  const handle2 = Meteor.subscribe('subcategories');
  const handle3 = Meteor.subscribe('products');
  const isReady1 = handle1.ready()
  const isReady2 = handle2.ready()
  const isReady3 = handle3.ready()
  return {
    products: isReady3 ? Products.find({}).fetch() : [],
    categories: isReady1 ? Categories.find({}).fetch() : [],
    subcats: isReady2 ? SubCategories.find({}).fetch(): [],
  };
 }, B2C);
```

It would be great if you could figure out what's happening or what mistake I'm making
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After removing all subscriptions and adding autopublish, it's working fine, but this I feel is not an improper solution, since I do not wish to publish all data everywhere, there must be a workaround right?

RESOLVED:
I put all the subscriptions in Meteor.isClient block, so yeah the subscriptions shouldn’t run on the server at all, even if the code is present on the client and one is using it for server-render, the Meteor.isClient block should be provided for the codes which might cause error on server render

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to monkey-patch the server side by adding `Meteor.subscribe` as a function that return an object with a `ready` function that always returns `true`:

Server-side:

```js
onPageLoad(sink => {
  const context = {};
  // monkey patching subscribe on the server to be ready immediately
  Meteor.subscribe = (topic) => ({ready: () => true});

  sink.renderIntoElementById("app", renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={sink.request.url} context={context}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  ));
});
```

This way you don't need to touch every component individually.